# RavenDB Service: how to set Access-Control-Expose-Headers?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http-headers, ravendb

I have a RavenDB instence running as a console app. Angular JS client fetches data via Raven HTTP API. It returns metadata such as ETag, document ID through response headers [image: Response Headers].

As [this post mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18124483/angularjs-ignoring-some-headers), Angular ignore most headers. My question is how to set Access-Control-Expose-Headers for RavenDB server to allow client see other headers?

Answer (score 0):

See here:

https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/3.0/Csharp/server/configuration/configuration-options

Raven/AccessControlAllowOrigin 
Configures the server to send Access-Control-Allow-Origin header with the specified value. If this value isn't specified, all the access control settings are ignored. 
Allowed values: null (don't send the header), *, http://example.org, 
Default: none (if this value isn't specified, all the access control settings are ignored)

Raven/AccessControlMaxAge 
Configures the server to send Access-Control-Max-Age header with the specified value.
Default: 1728000 (20 days)

Raven/AccessControlAllowMethods 
Configures the server to send Access-Control-Allow-Methods header with the specified value. 
Default: PUT, PATCH, GET, DELETE, POST.

Raven/AccessControlRequestHeaders 
Configures the server to send Access-Control-Request-Headers header with the specified value. 
Default: none

Comment: have read the document but cannot to see all headers. Here are my  settings: <add key="Raven/AccessControlAllowOrigin" value="http://localhost:60117" />
   <add key="Raven/AccessControlRequestHeaders" value="ETag,Raven-Clr-Type,Raven-Entity-Name" />. I leave AccessCntrolMaxAge and AccessControlAllowMethod with default value. It only allows angular see only header last-modified and content-type. Do i need add some headers to the request?

Comment: Ayende, I cannot make it work. Do you have a working example to allow browser access ETag and Raven-Clr-Type header? Thanks.

Comment: Setting `Raven/AccessControlRequestHeaders` to the relevant headers should do it.

Comment: Did that. But it doesn't work for me. Here is the sample repo at github: https://github.com/yumei/CorsHeaders.git.

Comment: And what do you get when you make requests using this configuration?

Comment: Only two headers exposed to browser: last-modified and content-type. But from Chrome's network tab, the complete response headers are: __document_id:clients/1
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://localhost:56408
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8
Date:Wed, 20 Jan 2016 13:56:40 GMT
ETag:"01000000-0000-0001-0000-000000000002"
Last-Modified:Mon, 18 Jan 2016 17:59:52 GMT
Raven-Clr-Type:eLtss.Domain.Client.Client, eLtss.Domain.Client
Raven-Entity-Name:clients
Raven-Last-Modified:2016-01-18T17:59:52.4913463Z
Raven-Server-Build:3660
Server:Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0